# Can't add directory to Python Path

Tags: bash, unix, directory, pythonpath, permanent

In my .bashrc I added the following:

export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/tbao/src/Cython-0.14.1

When I relogin, I get the error:

-bash: /home/tbao/src/Cython-0.14.1: is a directory

I want to add the the directory to my pythonpath, but I can't.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does $PYTHONPATH contain spaces?

Comment: Try adding a `/` at the end and see if it works.

Comment: I've added a / at the end and it doesn't work.  PYTHONPATH does not contain spaces.  I tried to echo $PYTHONPATH and got a newline, which was weird.

Comment: There's more to this story. Something else in your initialization files (e.g. .bashrc, .profile, .bash_profile) is using or setting PYTHONPATH in an unexpected way. Can you find it?

Comment: It sounds to me like there's an invisible character on that line of the .bashrc messing things up.  Can you view it with something that shows invisibles and see if anything turns up?

Comment: To check for non-printable characters in env-variables, you can use `env | cat -vet` then go through the output or use `env | od -c`

Answer (score 2):

I would guess that the comments about there being spaces in are spot on, to handle that, quote the right-hand side:

```
export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:$HOME/src/Cython-0.14.1"
```

Can you share what the current value of PYTHONPATH currently is?  Perhaps with something like:

```
echo $PYTHONPATH | tr : \\n
```

So it's split across multiple lines and easier to read.